# How can I save panes size inside local storage?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Following [splitpanes](https://github.com/antoniandre/splitpanes/tree/legacy) don't have built in local storage implementation. I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
<template>
  <CustomSplitpanes
    storage-key="key"
    ...
  >
    ...
  </CustomSplitpanes>
</template>

<script>
import CustomSplitpanes from '@/components/custom/custom-splitpanes'

export default {
  components: { CustomSplitpanes }
}
</script>
```

Before writing some pseudo code, I'm going to show you what I found out by looking at the source code.

[splitpanes.vue](https://github.com/antoniandre/splitpanes/blob/legacy/src/components/splitpanes/splitpanes.vue)

- Inside data function there's an array named `panes`, which might be used to cycle through each pane.
- Inside data function there's a boolean named `dragging`, which might be used to know if user is dragging the splitter.

**PSEUDO CODE**

custom-splitpanes.js

```
<script>
import { Splitpanes } from 'splitpanes'

export default {

  extends: Splitpanes,

  props: {
    storageKey: String
  },

  created () {
    this.$watch(() => this.touch.dragging, val => {
      // if dragging is false, save each pane size inside local storage
    })
  },

  mounted () {
    this.panes.forEach(pane => {
      // do more or less what's done inside updatePaneComponents method (splitpanes.vue),
      // but retrieve the pane size from local storage by looking for `${storageKey}-${pane.id}`
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

**ISSUES**

- Following implementation doesn't work when user double clicks a splitter.

**DOUBTS**

- Is `pane.id` a reliable value to be used as local storage key?
- Is this the proper way to implement local storage feature or am I missing anything?